# How do they decide if a tank is eliminated or not?

Tags: girls-und-panzer

In Sensha-dou, if the tank gets hit and is unable to continue the battle, it will raise a white flag. However, there are some cases when the tank got hit but still no flag raised. Here are some example:

- When the Duck Team (volleyball club team) hit St. Gloriana's Matilda tank, they hit it twice on close range but no flag. But when the Hippo Team hit the same type of tank once, that tank got flag.
- In OVA, when Ooarai Girls High School fought with Anzio High School, their Carro Veloce got hit several times, but still continued their battle. They just flipped their tank again.
- There was several cases when the rack got hit and came loose, but there was no flag and they fixed it right away. (None of their opponents seem to attack their tanks)
- Some other cases that I'm aware of probably because of their thick armor like Kuromorimine Girls High School's Mauss

**Note**: Most tanks only need one hit to raise a flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation takes into effect the power of the actual gun of each tank. The Type 89 the volleyball team used has terrible gun that can't even penetrate the ass of a British Matilda. The StuG III Ausf G that the Hippo team uses a gun that has better penetration.

For the Carro Veloce, their reasoning is that the tankettes are only flipped because of their small size and the computer that does the calculating doesn't register it as a penetrating shot.

As for the Maus, it's the same reasoning as question number 1. The Maus has very thick armor and regular hits from Ooarai's tanks will never penetrate.